# Include another param in "params" (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, parameters, .net-4.5

Having the exhaustive list of the `string.Format` definitions as

```
public static String Format(IFormatProvider provider,String format, params object[] args);
public static String Format(String format, params object[] args);
public static String Format(String format, object arg0, object arg1, object arg2);
public static String Format(String format, object arg0);
public static String Format(String format, object arg0, object arg1);
```

and the following code

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myFormat = "(0:'{0}';1:'{1}')";
        var myParams = new object[] {"arg1", "arg2"};       

        var myString = MyTest(myFormat, myParams);

        Console.WriteLine(myString);
    }

    public static string MyTest(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        string myFirstArg = "arg0";
        var result = string.Format(format, myFirstArg, args);
        return result;
    }
}
```

will give

```
(0:'arg0';1:'System.Object[]')
```

the question is now how to include the `arg0` in `myParams`, in order to have in output

```
(0:'arg0';1:'arg1';2:'arg2')
```

PS. (supposing `myFormat = "(0:'{0}';1:'{1}';2:'{2}')";`)

Comment: I would `List<object> newParams = args.ToList(); newParams.Add(myFirstArg); string.Format("blablabla", newParams.ToArray());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go with LINQ:

```
public static string MyTest(string format, params object[] args)
{
    string myFirstArg = "arg0";
    var result = String.Format(format, (new[] { myFirstArg }).Union(args).ToArray());
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create another array with arg0 as first elem. Try this:

```cs
using System.Linq;
public static string MyTest(string format, params object[] args) {
    var newarr = new object[] { "arg0" };
    newarr.Concat(args);
    var result = string.Format(format, newarr);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use *Prepend* extension method for such tasks:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string myFirstArg = "arg0";
        var format = "(0:'{0}';1:'{1}';2:'{2}')";
        var args = new object[] { "arg1", "arg2" };
        var result = string.Format(format, args.Prepend(myFirstArg).ToArray());
    }
}
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, T element)
    {
        yield return element;
        foreach (var e in collection) yield return e;
    }
}
```